# Display selected items in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

How to display selected items in a list?

So that the elements selected in the selector are displayed in the list below it.

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="md-form">
    <select name="users" multiple="multiple"
            required>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What should be the result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="users" multiple="multiple"
            required>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

Selected items:

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything/done any research? You seem to understand that events are part of it, so I would expect that you've tried something there...

Comment: No, I haven’t tried it, because I am not strong at Javascript. So far I’m only studying the backend to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check your selected is exist or not and create it.

```
if( document.getElementById("mySelect") != undefined) {
  document.getElementById("mySelect").remove();
}
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
```

And you `map` function to create options selected in `change` event handle as

```js
 function change (options) {
   var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("md-form")[0];
   if( document.getElementById("mySelect") != undefined) document.getElementById("mySelect").remove();
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
   let selected = [...options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => {
   
    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    selectList.multiple = "multiple";
    parent.appendChild(selectList);
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = o.value;
    option.text = o.text;
    selectList.appendChild(option);

   });
   
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="md-form">
    <select name="users" multiple="multiple"
            required onchange="change(this.options);">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to do something like that (added notes inside the code):

```js
const userSelection = document.querySelector('[name="users"]'); // select element
const userSelect = document.querySelector('ul'); // list container
userSelection.addEventListener('change', function() { // add event listener to change of the select
  const options = userSelection.querySelectorAll('option'); // list of options
  options.forEach(option => { // iterate them
    if(option.selected == true) { // if one of them selected
      const newLI = document.createElement('li'); // create li element
      newLI.textContent = option.value; // add the value of selected option as text content
      newLI.addEventListener('click', function() {  userSelect.removeChild(this); }); // BONUS: remove list item with click
      userSelect.appendChild(newLI); // append the new created li element to the list
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="md-form">
  <select name="users" multiple="multiple" required>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<ul></ul>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking that you could use JavaScript (JS) as a way to get the items that are selected and paste them elsewhere (wherever you want).

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="select" name="users" multiple="multiple"
            required>
        <option class="option" value="1">1</option>
        <option class="option" value="2">2</option>
        <option class="option" value="3">3</option>
    </select>

Selected items:

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Then add JS:

```
// Get the select input
document.getElementByID("select")

// Get the options
document.getElementByClassName("option")

// Get the options that are selected
var print = `.option:[active]`;

// Print (paste) the selected options elsewhere on the page
if print {
document.write(print);
}
```

Please tell me if this works, as it might not. After all, I'm just an 8-year old, and just starting to learning web development.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="md-form">
    <select name="users" multiple="multiple"
            required>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
// References to elements
var select = document.querySelector('select'),
  options = Array.from(select.querySelectorAll('option')),
  form = document.querySelector('.md-form'),
  ul = document.createElement('ul');

// Variables with information
var selected = [];

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  selected = [];
  ul.innerHTML = '';

  options.map(function(el) {
    if (el.selected) selected.push(el);
  });

  if (selected.length) {
    selected.map(function(el) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');

      li.textContent = el.textContent;

      ul.appendChild(li);
    });

    form.appendChild(ul);
  } else {
    form.removeChild(ul);
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1j7a9h35/